# Check if Progressive Web App is Already Installed

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I have a popup on my webpage prompting users to install our PWA. However, once it is installed I don't want to ask them again.

How can I check to see if the PWA is already installed?

Comment: Isn't this handled by the phone's software? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria

Comment: Yes it is, however, in newer versions of Chrome the banner does not pop-up automatically. I am actually using that page as a reference and capturing the prompt so display it myself. The issue is my system has untechy people using it and they will have problems finding the option to install themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code fixed this issue. First I have my button with `id="downloadli"` and by default it is hidden or `style="display:none"`

Since you have to add a listener to the `beforeinstallprompt` to trigger the install if you piggy back off that action to display the download button it will only work when install is possible.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
// Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
e.preventDefault();
// Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
deferredPrompt = e;

$('#downloadli').css('display', 'block');
});
```

This way if the app is already installed the `beforeinstallprompt` is not added to the page and the inside of this block is not run.

Answer (score 4):

You can't check if current user install PWA, But you can check if user is with pwa now with standalone display.

```
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
  // your code here
}
```

One solution is the track which users get the click on your button by listening for the [beforeinstallprompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent) event.

Comment: That was one thought, but is there a way to track if they uninstall the standalone?

Comment: My solution for this approach is the set a `status` for any user in localStorage and always check user's pwa status. e.x. null, installed, unistalled and etc.

Comment: if user be in your site, you have status of current user and if user be in pwa you can check with standalone display. All the time user track.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the feedback but I am still not sure how this would work. If they have it installed but they open it in browser, we can't assume that means they uninstalled it. Also if they have multiple devices this wouldn't work perfectly.

Comment: When current user want to install pwa, you cant set `install` status in localStorage with `beforeinstallprompt` event. plus, Any devices has separate pwa app

Comment: You should only show your install popup if you capture the beforeinstallprompt event. That event will never be fired again if it is installed (Chrome & edge?)

Comment: Here is a tester I use. It's from last year, so info on how all browsers handle a PWA is not up to date. Only after it sees beforeinstallprompt does it show a button to install https://a2hs.glitch.me/ . It will never show the button if already installed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right solution:

```
window.addEventListener('appinstalled', () => {
        setAppInstalled(true)
    })
```

Comment: This is more in line with the type of answer I was looking for. Note however that support for this is marginal right now, cf https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/appinstalled_event#browser_compatibility.